# No dispara el evento al detectar cambio de texto en el input

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, input

Tengo dos input donde en el primero se escribe y se visualiza como moneda y en el segundo toma el valor del primer input y lo cambia a numerico, este segundo input estara oculto es para que luego vaya a la base de datos, problema es que solo dispara el evento cuando uno escribe en el segundo input quiero que se dispare automáticamente de acuerdo al valor del primer input, el evento solo se dispara cuando uno escribe en el y no de acuerdo al primer input

```js
  const number = document.querySelector('.number');
  function getInputValue(inputElement) {
    return parseInt(inputElement.value.replace(/\D/g, ""));
  }

  function formatInputValue(inputElement) {
    let n = getInputValue(inputElement);
    inputElement.value = Number.isNaN(n) ? "$" : "$" + getInputValue(inputElement).toLocaleString().replace(/[.]+/g, ",");
  }

  number.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    formatInputValue(e.target);
    // Apply a formula
    let n = getInputValue(e.target);
  });

  function onSubmit(token) {
    document.getElementById("form-step").submit();
  }
  $("#currency-field").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
    $("#monto2").val(value);
  });
  $("#monto2").on('input paste', function() {
    let btn = $('.btn-next')
    let errorMsg = $('#errorMsg2')
    if (+$(this).val() < 100000 || +$(this).val() > 15000000) {
      errorMsg.show();
      btn.prop('disabled', true)
    } else {
      errorMsg.hide();
      btn.prop('disabled', false)
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="currency-field" id="currency-field" class="number" required>
<br>
<input type="text" name="monto2" id="monto2">
<br>
<span id="errorMsg2" style="display:none;">Menor que 100.000 o mayor a 15.000.000</span>
```

Comment: Ambos tienen un evento input pero, en tu evento del input2 es dónde muestras el mensaje de error. Tendrías que hacer la validación de la entrada en el evento del primero y sólo copiar el dato validado al segundo. Ya después harías el envío de los datos.

algo así

input2.Text = Validar(input1.Text);

Y sí sólo quieres el 2do input para respaldar el dato y parsearlo a entero, podrías guardarlo en una variable y ahorrarte ese input en tú ventana.

Comment: Como pudiera validar el primer input sin que tome el signo del $? por eso valido en el segundo que es donde el numero esta limpio sin signos ni nada :(

Comment: Pudieras colocarlo en un ejecutable para ver como funciona? Ya que asi no lo entiendo mucho amigo y disculpa

Comment: Claro, mira checa en este editor online, es una idea de lo que podrías hacer:

https://codepen.io/4cnologi4/pen/LYNzpYj?editors=1010